# Most efficient regex for checking if a string contains at least 3 alphanumeric characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex:

```
(?:.*[a-zA-Z0-9].*){3}
```

I use it to see if a string has at least 3 alphanumeric characters in it.  It seems to work.

Examples of strings it should match:

```
'a3c'
'_0_c_8_'
' 9 9d '
```

However, I need it to work faster.  Is there a better way to use regex to match the same patterns?

---

Edit:
I ended up using this [regex](https://www.regex101.com/r/cF0oA9/1) for my purposes:

```
(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]){3}
```

(no modifiers needed)

Comment: What regex flavor are you interested in?

Comment: @stribizhev I'm interested in ECMAScript regex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most efficient regex approach is to use the [principle of contrast](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast), i.e. using opposite character classes side by side. Here is a regex that can be used to check if a string has 3 Latin script letters or digits:

```
^(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]){3}
```

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/vD9lR8/1).

In case you need a full string match, you will need to append `.*` (or `.*$` if you want to guarantee you will match all up to the end of string/line), but in my tests on regexhero, `.*` yields better performance):

```
^(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]){3}.*
```

Also, a lot depends on the engine. PCRE has auto-optimizations in place that consists in auto-possessification (i.e. it turns the `*` to `*+` in `(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9]*+`).

See [more details on password validation optimizations](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#password) here.

Comment: The regex can be anchored, and the `.*` removed.

Comment: I have checked several things, and it turns out that `(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]){3}.*` is really slower than `^(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]){3}` (~17%). I edited the answer. I believe that the start of string anchor is really helpful here, I tested against the provided input on regexhero, and the `(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]){3}.*` pattern yielded 422,318 iterations per second, the `(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]){3}` (without `.*`) yielded 341,375 ips, and `^(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]){3}` yielded ... 1,371,000 ips :)

Comment: Without testing, it's easy to see that `.*` will either be equal or slower (usually slower, since the engine needs to check whether the rest of the string has new line character or not, though it can skip in `s` mode). The `^` will force the match to be carried out only at the beginning of the string, so of course, it avoids searching from subsequent indices when there is no match from index 0.

Answer (score 3):

```
(?:.*?[a-zA-Z0-9]){3}.*
```

You can use this.This is much faster and takes much lesser steps than yours.See demo.You probably would want to use `^$` anchors too to make sure there are no partial matches.

https://regex101.com/r/nS2lT4/32

The reason is

```
(?:.*[a-zA-Z0-9].*){3}

                ^^
```

This actually consumes the whole string and then engine has to backtrack.When using the other regex this is avoided

Comment: if its ok to match underscore also, replace charset with \w also improves a little the performance

Comment: @RodrigoLópez m not very sure OP wants that :(

Answer (score 2):

Just consider this. Regular expressions are powerful because they're expressive and very flexible (with features such as look-ahead, greedy consumption and back-tracking). There will almost *always* be a cost to that, however minor.

If you want *raw* speed (and you're willing to give up the expressiveness), you may find that it's faster to bypass regular expressions altogether and just evaluate the string, such as with the following pseudo-code:

```
def hasThreeAlphaNums(str):
    alphanums = 0
    for pos = 0 to len(str) - 1:
        if str[pos] in set "[a-zA-Z0-9]":
            alphanums++
            if alphanums == 3:
                return true
    return false
```

It's a parser (a very simple one in this case), a tool that can be even *more* powerful than regular expressions. For a more concrete example, consider the following C code:

```
#include <ctype.h>
int hasThreeAlphaNums (char *str) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int ch = *str; ch != '\0'; str++)
        if (isalnum (ch))
            if (++count == 3)
                return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, as to whether or not that's faster for this specific case, that depends on many factors, such as whether the language is interpreted or compiled, how efficient the regex is under the covers, and so on.

That's why the mantra of optimisation is *"Measure, don't guess!"*  You should evaluate the possibilities in your target environment.

Comment: I didn't select this as the answer since it didn't answer my question.

However, I think it's good advice, so thanks and +1.

Comment: @user3772517, that's okay, it's sometimes good to look at _other_ solutions beyond the limits imposed by the question, since the questioner doesn't always get that right. But, if you need a regex, then you need a regex, there's no getting around that :-)